# Node.js async/await does not wait for return of function executing sql stored procedure

Tags: node.js, stored-procedures, async-await, synchronous

I am have an function that executes sql stored procedure. By itself, function works as expected.
When I call that function from node.js route async/await doesn't wait for a return value.
Relevant code is below:

```
router.post('/new_item', async (req, res)=> {  
   try {
      let sp_name = req.body.sp_name;
      let sp_params = req.body.sp_params;
      let sql_sp_call_status = 'in-progress'
      sql_sp_call_status = await sql_sp_execute(sp_name, sp_params)
      console.log('2- ' + sql_sp_call_status)
   } catch (err) {
      res.status(500)
      console.log(err)
      res.send(err.message)
   }
  res.json('done')
})
-----------
async function sql_sp_execute(sp_name, sp_params){
  const pool = await poolPromise
  const req = await pool.request();
  await sp_params.forEach(function(param) {
    let ptype1 = sql.TYPES[param.type]
    req.input(param.name, ptype1, param.value);
  });
  await req.execute(sp_name, (err, recordset) => {
  if (err) {
        console.log(err) 
        return 'sql_call_failed'
     }else{
        console.log( '1-success')
        return 'sq_sp_call_success';
     }
   });
}
```

I expect to see in the console :

```
1-success
2-sq_sp_call_succes
```

But it looks like this:

```
2- undefined
POST /.../new_item 200 1.300 ms - 6
1- success
```

Comment: Reduce to a minimal reproduction case. There is still lots of unnecessary code - removing this may reveal insights.

Comment: @user2864740 I am sorry, i don't know what you mean

Comment: For example, eliminate all sql parameters such that only the “execute” - does the same issue exist? If so, look for the next superfluous code..

Comment: @user2864740. Let me try. Thanks

Comment: Anyway, that behavior seems valid. The SQL call is probably not _blocking_ as expected - and it’s _internal_ sync handlers fire later, after the outside await-unwinding.

Comment: @user2864740. Without sql calls, it behaves as expected

Comment: Example, replace the SQL call with: await setTimeout(() => console.log(“1-timeout”), 100) — does the same behavior persist? I suspect it does, as the call accepts a callback functions to process the result. Check the API, and verify the nature of the call. As with setTimout, such is probably not blocking or returning a Promise.

Comment: @goryef where is `poolPromise` coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the keyword `await` on a callback expression, so it won't behave as you expect.

```js
  await req.execute(sp_name, (err, recordset) => {...}) // awaiting a callback expression
```

One thing you could do is use the function `promisify` exported in Node's `util` module.

```js
const { promisify } = require('util')

// ...
  const recordset = await promisify(req.execute.bind(req))(sp_name) // now node will wait
  // note: err is thrown if it errors
```